# Batch - Appending strings

Tags: string, loops, batch-file, paste

I'm trying to make a for statement that have to echo a string that contains only two character.
The type of string would by like "aaabbb".
My problem is that the echo command make a new line each time I call it, so if I write something like:

```
FOR %%i IN (<condition>) DO ECHO a
FOR %%i IN (<condition>) DO ECHO b
```

The result would be something like:

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

What I thought was "Maybe echoing a unique string?"
So I wondering if that a method to append a character/variable in another variable.

Thank you for your support,
Waiting for a response,
Dave.

Comment: Please do not edit your question / title with the solution.  Instead, post an answer to your question and describe what the solution was, then accept your answer.  This marks the question as resolved and makes it easier for people to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your own solution. However, @templatetypedef is right. This site is designed in such a way that it works much better when a solution is posted as an answer instead of being incorporated into the question. Once you've accepted an answer (which would be your own answer in this case), there will be an indication in the list of questions that your question is solved, so you don't need to add `SOLVED` to the title either. Please do consider editing your question and reposting the solution as suggested. Either way, thanks again for the solution.

Comment: Thank you guys for the support, I'm new and I don't know very well how the entire site works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
@ECHO off &SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:vars
    SET "fC=a"
    SET "sC=b"
    SET "toEcho="

    PAUSE

    FOR /L %%f IN (1, 1, 3) DO (
        IF %%f == 1 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%fC%"
        IF %%f == 2 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%fC%"
        IF %%f == 3 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%fC%"
    )

    FOR /L %%f IN (4, 1, 6) DO (
        IF %%f == 4 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%sC%"
        IF %%f == 5 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%sC%"
        IF %%f == 6 SET "toEcho=!toEcho!%sC%"
    )

    ECHO %toEcho%

GOTO end

:end
    PAUSE
```

The real project was a bar.
I give the percentage of the done level as a parameter to a label and it make for me a full loading bar!

The first parameter is the how-big-the-bar-have-to-be info.

```
:bar size loaded
    CLS

    SET /A "toDo=(%~1*%~2)/100"
    SET /A "remains=%~1-%toDo%"
    ECHO %~2%%

    SET "bar_up=%corUL%"
    FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %~1) DO SET "bar_up=!bar_up!%linHo%"
    SET "bar_up=!bar_up!%corUR%
    ECHO %bar_up%

    SET "bar_ce=%linVe%"
    FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %toDo%) DO SET "bar_ce=!bar_ce!%barDo%"
    FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %remains%) DO SET "bar_ce=!bar_ce!%barSp%"
    SET "bar_ce=!bar_ce!%linVe%
    ECHO %bar_ce%

    SET "bar_do=%corDL%"
    FOR /L %%i IN (1, 1, %~1) DO SET "bar_do=!bar_do!%linHo%"
    SET "bar_do=!bar_do!%corDR%
    ECHO %bar_do%

    EXIT /B
```

The others variables are:

corUL = the left-up corner character

corUR = the right-up corner character

corDL = the left-down corner character

corDR = the right-down corner character

linHo = the horizontal line character

linVe = the vertical line character

barDo = the character that indicate the done-part of the bar

barSp = the character that indicate the empty-part of the bar